# getAccessToken() method returns null in facebook PHP SDK 5

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Hi I'm facing a problem which I couldn't find solution on net. I'm trying to log into my website using facebook login. This is my code. getAccessToken() method always returns null. Please Help me to resolve this error. Thank you. Below is my code.

this is my fbConfig.php file

```
    <?php
    if(!session_id()){
        session_start();
    }

    //Include the autoloader provided in the SDK
    require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\FBFunApp\php-graph-sdk-5.x\src\Facebook\autoload.php';


    //Include required libraries
    use Facebook\Facebook;
    use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
    use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

    /*
     * Configuration and setup Facebook SDK
    */
    $appId         = '560615054394144'; //Facebook App ID
    $appSecret     = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'; //Facebook App Secret
    $redirectURL   = 'http://localhost:8080/FBFunApp/views/login.php'; //Callback URL
    $fbPermissions = array('email');  //Optional permissions


    $fb = new Facebook(array('app_id' => $appId,'app_secret' => $appSecret,'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',));

    // Get redirect login helper
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    // Try to get access token
    try {  
        if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){ 
            $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
        }else{ 
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken(); 
            var_dump($accessToken); //returns null
        }
    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo 'Exception: '+$e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }   

?>
```

This is login.php file. Config file is used inside this.

```
<?php 
    //Include FB config file & User class
    require_once '../config/fbConfig.php';
    require_once '../controllers/User.php';

    if(isset($accessToken)){
        if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
            $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        }else{
            //Put short-lived access token in session
            $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

            // OAuth 2.0 client handler helps to manage access tokens
            $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

            // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
            $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

            // Set default access token to be used in script
            $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        }

        // Redirect the user back to the same page if url has "code" parameter in query string
        if(isset($_GET['code'])){ 
            header('Location: ./');                 
        }

        // Getting user facebook profile info
        try {
            $profileRequest = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,cover,picture');
            $fbUserProfile = $profileRequest->getGraphNode()->asArray();
            print_r($fbUserProfile);
        } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) { 
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            session_destroy();
            // Redirect user back to app login page
            header("Location: ./");
            exit;
        } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

        // Initialize User class
        $user = new User();

        // Insert or update user data to the database
        $fbUserData = array(
            'oauth_provider'=> 'facebook',
            'oauth_uid'     => $fbUserProfile['id'],
            'first_name'    => $fbUserProfile['first_name'],
            'last_name'     => $fbUserProfile['last_name'],
            'email'         => $fbUserProfile['email'],
            'gender'        => $fbUserProfile['gender'],
            'locale'        => $fbUserProfile['locale'],
            'cover'         => $fbUserProfile['cover']['source'],
            'picture'       => $fbUserProfile['picture']['url'],
            'link'          => $fbUserProfile['link']
        );

        $userData = $user->checkUser($fbUserData);      


        // Put user data into session
        $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;

        // Get logout url
        $logoutURL = $helper->getLogoutUrl($accessToken, $redirectURL.'views/logout.php');

        // Render facebook profile data
        if(!empty($userData)){
            $output  = '<h2 style="color:#999999;">Facebook Profile Details</h2>';
            $output .= '<div style="position: relative;">';
            $output .= '<img src="'.$userData['cover'].'" />';
            $output .= '<img style="position: absolute; top: 90%; left: 25%;" src="'.$userData['picture'].'"/>';
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= '<br/>Facebook ID : '.$userData['oauth_uid'];
            $output .= '<br/>Name : '.$userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name'];
            $output .= '<br/>Email : '.$userData['email'];
            $output .= '<br/>Gender : '.$userData['gender'];
            $output .= '<br/>Locale : '.$userData['locale'];
            $output .= '<br/>Logged in with : Facebook';
            $output .= '<br/>Profile Link : <a href="'.$userData['link'].'" target="_blank">Click to visit Facebook page</a>';
            $output .= '<br/>Logout from <a href="'.$logoutURL.'">Facebook</a>'; 
        }else{
            $output = '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
        }       
    }else{
        // Get login url        
        $loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $fbPermissions); 

        // Render facebook login button
        $output = '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($loginURL).'"><img src="../images/app/fb-login.png"></a>';
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login with Facebook</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Display login button / Facebook profile information -->
    <div><?php echo $output; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not even sending the user through the login flow here by the looks of it, so where do you expect an access token to come from …? The documentation has examples on how to implement login, go check those.

Comment: @misorude This is my FBCOnfig.php file. I have implemented the login flow in another file-login.php. And I use this config file inside the login.php

Comment: No exceptions? (Btw., that should be a `.` in your last catch branch and not a `+`) Does the rest of the flow work as expected (login dialog shows, you get redirected back to your redirect URI with a `code` appended to the URL, ...)?

Comment: @misorude Yes.No exceptions. (I did the correction.Thankz for it) Login Dialog is not visible. Redirection also not happened as expected way. But user information is retrieved. I have attached my login.php file. Thank you.

Comment: _“But user information is retrieved.”_ - that would be impossible, if you did not have a valid user access token at this point.

Comment: @misorude It's true. First time when the user logs into system, no login dialog and incorrect directing page. For the second time user tries to log into system, then it is redirected to the page with user information display. But always the access token is null. I can't figure out the error.

Answer (score 0):

After the updation of facebook api :
Every request Url must be `Https`
So,

Change this :-

`$redirectURL   = 'http://localhost:8080/FBFunApp/views/login.php'; //Callback URL`

To :

`$redirectURL   = 'https://localhost:8080/FBFunApp/views/login.php'; //Callback URL`

You can do this using Changing your webserver setting Or using it's defaylt port :- 443 for ssl.

Happy Coding :)